# Setting the same height to fluid div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the same height of a group of div's that have a fluid height but a fixed width.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var heightArray = $(".feature_content_body").map(function () {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get();
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, Max, heightArray);
        $(".feature_content_body").height(maxHeight);
    });
</script>
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong here as i can see the logic in the code that should make it work...

Can someone please shed some light on my issue here?

Here is [a demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/zzf7r/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line...

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, Max, heightArray);
```

...should be...

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, heightArray);
```

Referencing `Max` there will be a `ReferenceError`, unless you have defined it or you're running this in `with (Math) { }`.

Comment: thank you Alex appreciated this was the issue. Must have just overlooked this due to looking at the code for so long and doing numerous pages in the last few days.